# calling serial.read from other function

Tags: python, arduino

I'm trying to connect python with Arduino code using serial but I cannot call `serial.read()` within the `led_on_off()` function.

This is the Arduino code:

```
int led=13;
int val=0;
char functionname='K';
#include <string.h>
void setup() 
   { 
      Serial.begin(9600); 
      pinMode(led, OUTPUT);
      digitalWrite (led, LOW);
      Serial.println("Connection established...");
   }

void loop()
{

    functionname = Serial.read();
 if (functionname= 'L')
  {
    led_on_off();
    }

 }//void loop
void led_on_off()
{
  val=Serial.read()
  if (val= 1)
  digitalWrite(led,HIGH) 
  else if (val == 0)
  digitalWrite(led,LOW)
}
```

And this is the python code:

```
import serial    


Arduino_Serial = serial.Serial('com18',9600)  # Create Serial port object called arduinoSerialData
print(Arduino_Serial.readline())             # read the serial data and print it as line
print("Enter L to ON LED and M dc motor") 



input_data = input()                  
Arduino_Serial.write(input_data.encode())
print(Arduino_Serial.readline())
input_value=input("enter 1 or 0")      
Arduino_Serial.write(input_value.encode())
```

my expectation is to get input `(1 or 0)` from python code and process it within the led_on_off function in Arduino code using the `serial.read()` function and turn on or off the led at pin 13.

Comment: The `val = 1` is assigment, it sets val to 1. If it's used as a condition, it's always true. There is a huge difference between `=` (assigment operator) and `==` (equality operator).

Comment: And the arduino code is actually C++ and it has some rules. For example, each command have to be ended with semicolon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As already stated by @KIIV your Arduino code has some syntax errors. Besides that, you are sending a string from your Python script (`input` function) so you need to read it as a string on Arduino. Something like this would do the job:

Python script:

```
import serial


# Create Serial port object called arduinoSerialData
Arduino_Serial = serial.Serial('com18', 9600)
# read the serial data and print it as line
print(Arduino_Serial.readline())

input_data = input("Enter L to ON LED and M dc motor: ")
Arduino_Serial.write(input_data.encode())
print("Received Command:", Arduino_Serial.readline())
while True:
    input_value = input("enter 1 or 0")
    Arduino_Serial.write(input_value.encode())
```

Arduino code:

```
int led = 13;

void setup()
{
    Serial.begin(9600);
    pinMode(led, OUTPUT);
    digitalWrite(led, LOW);
}

void loop()
{
    //void loop
    if (Serial.available())
    {
        String functionname = Serial.readString();
        if (functionname == "L")
        {
            Serial.println("Command received from Arduino!");
            while (1)
            {
                led_on_off();
            }
        }
    }
}
void led_on_off()
{
    if (Serial.available())
    {
        String val = Serial.readString();
        if (val == "1")
            digitalWrite(led, HIGH);
        else if (val == "0")
            digitalWrite(led, LOW);
    }
}
```

Comment: M.R. thanks for your answer but your code works well in serial monitor but in python it stops responding after printing  "Enter L to ON LED and M dc motor: "

Comment: @russom I forgot to remove `String.print` from Arduino code. Check the new code, I also added a loop to the python script to be able to input multiple times.

Comment: what if i want to add other function called dc_motor() and go to it after going to the led_on_off() function thanks in advance

Comment: You can call `dc_motor` inside `led_on_off` when a value received. I suggest you create an algorithm for your problem then try to do some code.

Comment: What's the reason for  `   while (1)` in your answer?  You will never check for 'L' versus 'M' again ...

Comment: Why do you use String objects for single characters ?